# How can I detect the earliest instance of a non-NA value?

Tags: r

I have a data frame which lists events against the dates they occurred.

How can I record the first date a non-`NA` value appears in the dataset?

For example, given this dataset:

```
Colour       Date  
<chr>        <date>    
Blue         2021-06-29
NA           2021-03-10
NA           2021-04-02
Amber        2021-04-09
Blue         2021-06-21
NA           2021-03-09
Blue         2021-04-11
Amber        2021-05-21
NA           2021-02-17
```

How can I find the first/earliest time a non-`NA` value appears in terms of date/history?

In this example, the result would be `Amber, 2021-04-09` as the values that occur before it in time are all `NA` up until this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need the first non-NA by 'Date', `arrange` first and then `slice` the first row

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   arrange(is.na(Colour), Date) %>% 
   slice_head(n = 1)
```

-output

```
Colour       Date
1  Amber 2021-04-09
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Colour = c("Blue", NA, "Amber", "Blue", NA, "Blue", 
"Amber", NA), Date = structure(c(18807, 18696, 18726, 18799, 
18695, 18728, 18768, 18675), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Nice (although I've made one change). Would you explain how and why this works?

Comment: I negated `is.na` (to become `!is.na`).

Comment: @Mus Regarding why this works.  I assume that you only want to subset the row that comes after the first NA.  So, the `lag` of `is.na`, switches the position to next row where it is TRUE or may use `which` wrapped directly on the `is.na` and add (`+ 1`), but this may also have an issue when there are no NAs

Comment: How strange. I tried the solution with my dataset (the one I gave is an altered version of it for confidentiality reasons) and it didn't work - it returned an `NA` result, but when I added in the `!`, it returned the correct result. However, when I use your `df1`, it works as you have listed it.

Comment: @Mus It depends on the logic you wanted.  In your earlier version, it was the non-NA based logic that worked.  Here, with the altered data, it seems that you want to return the first row after the first NA

Comment: @Mus Your description `In this example, the result would be Amber, 2021-04-09 as the values before it are all NA.` is not correct because the first row is `Blue         2021-06-29` which is non-Na

Comment: Ultimately, I want to return the date of the row where the first non-`NA` value appears, so the earliest non-`NA` value.

Comment: And yes, the data set I have given is not sorted. I specify the "earliest" one in terms of time / the date listed against it. By "the ones before it," I am referring to the ones which occur before the first non-`NA` value in time.

Comment: @Mus ok, got it.  I updated with `arrange`

Comment: @Mus or use `df1 %>% na.omit %>% arrange(Date) %>% slice_head(n = 1)`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try the code below

```
> subset(df[order(df$Date), ], min(which(!is.na(Colour))) == seq_along(Colour))
  Colour       Date
3  Amber 2021-04-09
```

Answer (score 1):

Order the date, drop `NA` values and select the first row.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% arrange(Date) %>% na.omit() %>% slice(1L)

#  Colour       Date
#1  Amber 2021-04-09
```

In base R -

```
na.omit(df1[order(df1$Date), ])[1, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any library:

```
df1 = df[order(df$Date),] # orders by date
df1[which(!is.na(df1$Colour))[1],] # pick the first non-empty colour
```